# Is it possible to use the builtin "read" with local, readonly, or declare options?

Tags: bash

When using the bash builtin "read" to set a variable from user input, is it possible to set that variable as local (in a function), readonly, or use various declare options (e.g. declare -i)?

If not, how do you deal robustly with variables that are read from user input? I'd rather minimize globals that are lying around in my scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the readonly attribute on later time:

```
local A
read A
readonly A
A=1 ## error
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to variable to be local you may declare the variable before calling read?:

```
local input
read input
```

If it should be an array, read supports the `-a` switch:

```
local arr
read -a arr
<type>foo bar 123
```

`readonly` variable can't be passed to `read`. This is because `read` will attempt to write the input data to the variable:

```
readonly foo
read foo
<type> ...
```

Output:

```
test.sh: line 2: foo: readonly variable
```

You could use this workaround: (but check @gniourf_gniourf's comment)

```
local tmp
read tmp

readonly variable="$tmp"
```

You might also read into integer vars which have been declared using `-i`. Any non numeric input would be interpreted as `0` in this case:

```
declare -i number
read number
<type>ABC

echo "$number" # 0

declare -i number
read number
<type>123

echo "$number" # 123
```

Comment: That's a good start. It seems like it would work for most of such settings. Would it work for "readonly" as well?

Comment: I guess not, since read would attempt to write to the variable

Comment: @labyrinth what you can do is read your variable and after that declare it read only: `read input; declare -r input`.

Comment: I don't know who was first with this, hek2mgl or konsolebox, but since I started dialog with hek2mgl I'll go with yours. Thanks!

Comment: No problem :) Have also added examples for other use cases.